# Is it possible to create a key vault in Azure via c#

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to create a Key Vault in Azure via c#?  I'm able to manipulate secrets and keys via the KeyVaultClient but I need to

A). See if a key vault already exists and 
B). Create a key vault if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the KeyVault management client to list where a key vault exists in an Azure subscription and create the KeyVault if necessary.  There is C# SDK for these operations which are against Azure Resource Manager.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.vaultsoperationsextensions?view=azure-dotnet